# Paypal add to cart option button does not work in sandbox testing environment

Tags: drop-down-menu, paypal, selection

I am trying to test the following code in paypal sandbox environment but it is returning an error. Below is the code that I plug into the button script.

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/*********"   method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="***********">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Name of drop-down  menu">Select A Date:</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="$25.00">Saturday August 15, 2015</option>
<option value="$25.00">Saturday August 29, 2015</option>
</select> </td></tr>
```

This is the error message "PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem."

On the checkout page I should see the selected option and the value which is the cost but I am not seeing anything in the sandbox.

Could someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: can you post your complete code and the error

Comment: "returning an error."  Gonna need more info than that.  Error code, error message..??